# Junk Characters Coming while Decoding Data in Base 64

Tags: java, base64, apache-nifi

I am getting PDF content which is Base 64 encoded. I tried to decode it using NIFI with Processor Base64EncodeContent. The Decoded file I am sending in mail. Below is small sample of output coming in mail.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbeEs.jpg)

"No data should be available in . ¹  Check if sent . .  All documents are sent as pdf to*  9     :  ’   ³:  >  <    âA  m¬‘²@%é‚ÇŽÇ¢|ÀÈ™$ÉØ²§Uû÷LÒTB¨ l,îåù˜$â´º?6N¬JC¤ŒÃ°‰_Ïg -æ¿;ž‰ìÛÖYl`õ?èÓÌ[  ÿÿ PK"

How to extract the data in PDF as sent by third party?

I have tried to decode it using JAVA code and there also its failing. Not able to open the PDF, junk characters coming there too.

ConvertedJPGPDF.pdf file used below contains Base64 encoded String.

```
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\";
    String originalFileName = "ConvertedJPGPDF.pdf";
    String newFileName = "test.pdf";

    byte[] input_file = 
    Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath+originalFileName));


   // byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(input_file);
    byte[] decodedBytes1 = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(input_file);


    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath+newFileName);
    fos.write(decodedBytes1);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Comment: Note that a PDF file is not a plain text file; if you treat it as if it is plain text, you'll get unreadable, random looking characters.

Comment: I tried same as ConvertedJPGPDF.txt , not getting expected PDF. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should **not** treat a PDF file as if it is a text file, that will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that the file contains base64 encoded string already.

> ConvertedJPGPDF.pdf file used below contains Base64 encoded String.

So, you don't need to run this line:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(input_file);
```

By doing so, you are trying to encode those bytes again.

Directly decode the `input_file` array and then save the obtained byte array into a .pdf file.

**Update:**

The `ConvertedJPGPDF.pdf` doesn't really have to be named *`.pdf`*. It's really a plain text file considering that it is base 64 encoded.

Anyway, the following piece of code is working for me:

```
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\";
    String originalFileName = "ConvertedJPGPDF.pdf";
    String newFileName = "test.pdf";

    byte[] input_file = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath+originalFileName));

    byte[] decodedBytes1 = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(input_file);

    Files.write(Paths.get(filePath+newFileName), decodedBytes1);
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Done, but still not getting expected output.

Comment: May be the 3rd party pdf is already corrupted. May be it has fonts that your system does not recognize and you're seeing gibberish.

Comment: May be, 3rd Party is proving this data in xml tags as <pdfContent>.... Base64EncodedString... </pdfContent>

Comment: In xml provided, third party was providing corrupted data in few <pdfcontent> tag. Now the file provided is good and I am able to decode the content easily.